# Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL from http://app-name.herokuapp.com:undefined/api/auth/login

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I am facing an error while making the POST login request.

I had deployed the frontend on Netlify [here](https://61e7c30ba3c9d58a9fe302e2--nifty-goldwasser-573c0f.netlify.app/login) and the backend on Heroku [here](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/my-notebook-mohit/logs).
This is my backend logs https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/my-notebook-mohit/logs . which is working fine.

### Problem I facing

When I make a POST request on the login button from **frontend deployed on Netlify**, it goes to `http://my-notebook-mohit.herokuapp.com:${port}/api/auth/login` but shows the error

```
Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL from http://app-name.herokuapp.com:undefined/api/auth/login
```

**My index.js**

```
const connectToMongo = require('./db');
const express = require('express');


connectToMongo();
var cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
const port = 5000

//to use req body
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

//Available routes
app.use('/api/auth',require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/api/notes',require('./routes/notes'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT , () => {
  console.log(`my-notebook backend listening at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT }`)
})
```

**LoginPage.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import imgpath from "../assets/notepic.jpg";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const Login = (props) => {
  let history = useHistory();
  let port = process.env.PORT;
  ....
 
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch(`https://my-notebook-mohit.herokuapp.com:${port}/api/auth/login`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: credentials.email,
        password: credentials.password,
      }),
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    if (json.success === true) {
      //storing the authtoken
      localStorage.setItem("token", json.authToken);
      props.showAlert("User logged in successfully", "info");
      history.push("/");
    } else {
      props.showAlert("invalid Credentials", "danger");
    }
    console.log(json);
  };

  return (
   .....
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="login-form">
           .....
           ....
   </form>
  ...
  ...

};

export default Login;
```

[image: error1]

#### What to do ??

Comment: The `undefined` in the URL seems pretty clear. In `let port = process.env.PORT;`, `process.env.PORT;` is `undefined` (probably doesn't exist at all). Whatever layer is supposed to fill that in for your client-side code isn't doing so. (Something **is** creating `process.env`, which doesn't automatically exist client-side, or the error would be different.) Sounds like you need to put `PORT=5000` in some `.env` file or similar, but check the documentation of what you're using for details.

Comment: The port is filled by Heroku, maybe I can replace it  by `process.env.PORT || 5000`

Comment: Clearly, though, it's **not** being filled in by Heroku. :-) Yes, you could do what you show to default to 5000 if no `PORT` is on `process.env` (or if it's `0` or another falsy value).

Comment: This is not working man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I make a POST request on the login button from frontend deployed
> on Netlify, it goes to
> `http://my-notebook-mohit.herokuapp.com:${port}/api/auth/login` but
> shows the error
>
> ```
> Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL from http://app-name.herokuapp.com:undefined/api/auth/login
> ```

As it probably should. `port` is undefined here.

Netlify has no way of knowing what port Heroku assigned to your app, and Heroku has no way to inject any port information into your client-side code hosted elsewhere.

The good news is that Netlify doesn't need to know what port Heroku assigned to your back-end app. That is the port your back-end should bind to, but it is *not* the port used to connect to your app. How would clients ever connect if the port changed unpredictably?

Connect to your back-end using the standard HTTPS (or, if you must, HTTP) port. These are port 443 for HTTPS and port 80 for HTTP, but the easiest thing to do is omit the port entirely:

```
https://my-notebook-mohit.herokuapp.com/api/auth/login
```

Since we are using HTTPS here, any well-behaved client will default to port 443. This request will be received by Heroku's routers and routed to your app.

You can, and should, use HTTPS instead of HTTP for virtually all connections these days. This is especially important for security-related requests like this login request.